# calculate (find the type of isomorphism) of $ℤ_{p^n}/pℤ_{p^n}$ where p is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

calculate (find the type of isomorphism) of $ℤ_{p^n}/pℤ_{p^n}$ where p is prime.

I know that $ℤ/pℤ$ isomorphic to $ℤ_p$

and that  $ℤ_p/pℤ_p$ isomorphic to $Z_p$

any help and explanation on how to continue will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideals in a quotient $A/\mathfrak{a}$ correspond bijectively with the ideals in $A$ which contain $\mathfrak{a}$. In this way $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}/ p\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/((p)+(p^n)) = \mathbb{Z}/(p) = \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: it's $Z_{p^n}$ just edited the title

Comment: my mistake, fixed it

Comment: can you explain i did not understand how you got the isomorphism and how you got to the solution from that

Comment: I believe its often called the third isomorphism theorem... basically the idea is that the ideal $p \mathbb{Z}_{p^n} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ is the extension of $(p) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Z}/(p^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ (since $(p^n) \subseteq (p)$.) Then $(\mathbb{Z}/ (p^n))/((p^n)/(p)) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(p)$.

Comment: 1. The OP is asking for a *group* isomorphism. 2. I don't know how the knowledge of the correspondence of ideals helps to find an isomorphism. 3. Your last comment is much more suitable as an answer than the answer itself.